# Laravel PDF Generation with Google Map Issue

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am using Barryvdh DOMPDF to generate a pdf from view to PDF in Laravel . Everything is working fine other than a Google Map. This is how I am doing

1. Created a new root

   ```
   Route::get('/printPDF', 'Printer@printPDF');
   ```

   2. In Printer Controller, created a function printPDF and call Google Map Api to get and save map on the server

      ```
      $sMapa= public_path("temp/test5".".png");
      $image = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='
      . $sLat. ",". $sLong
      . '&maptype=hybrid'
      .'&zoom=18&size=510x250&markers=size:tiny|color:red|'
      . $sLat. ",". $sLong);

      $fp= fopen($sMapa, 'w+');
      fputs($fp, $image);
      fclose($fp);
      ```

It created the map and save it as Test5.png file on server.

Now we load the view to generate PDF and use test5.png in that view, with absolute path.

```
    $pdf = "";
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('main_pdf', $data);
    $file = "data/report/".$pdf_filename;
    file_put_contents($file, $pdf->output());
```

PDF is generated but the Map (test5.png) is not correctly placed, it is distorted. like this [image: See the attachment]

Can someone please figure out what is the issue and how to fix it?

The image on the server is fine and not damaged.

Comment: when you just open test5.png is the image distorted as well or not ?

Comment: It is not distorted, if we open it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I dit it in this way and it worked nicely.

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='
. $sLat. ",". $sLong
. '&maptype=hybrid'
.'&zoom=18&size=510x250&markers=size:tiny|color:red|'
. $sLat. ",". $sLong);
```

// Save the image in your server

```
Storage::put('public/folder/'.'somename'.png', $image);
```

And just look for it on the view your are transforming to pdf

For example:

```
  <img src="{{ url('/') }}{{ Storage::url('folder/'somename'.png')}}" alt="" style="width: 100%;">
```

I hope this helps.